# Casting on solidity vs a constructor

Tags: solidity

I am looking at some sample code on Github and I don't know if what is to the left of the "=" is type casting or a constructor.  I tried Googling this for 20 minutes but couldn't find an answer.

```
import "./ERC721.sol";
...
...
...
ERC721 asset = ERC721(_assetAddress);
```

The definition for ERC721 is below.  I don't see any constructor that takes in an address, but with Solidity I can never be sure if I'm missing some global automatic function or something

https://github.com/martinzugnoni/auction-engine/blob/master/contracts/ERC721.sol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't know if what is to the left of the "=" is type casting or a
> constructor.

Your first idea is right, this is just casting an `address` to `ERC721`.

If it were a smart contract creation, it would require the use of the `new` keyword as per [the documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.14/control-structures.html?highlight=new#creating-contracts-via-new) which would lead to a contract deployment like so :

```
// Contract Creation
ERC721 asset = new ERC721( /* constructor parameters */);
```

Answer (score 0):

It can seems a declaration concern constructor but in really that he made is to instanciate ERC721 smart contract definition with address about asset definition. In fact, for use the methods inside other smart contract you must to instanciate it with this statement:

```
[smartContractName] variable = [smartContractName]([addressSmartContractDeployed]);
```

Only when you instantiate a specific contract you can call its methods.

Comment: im sorry i dont understand your first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to access an already deployed contract in your own contract, we need to create an instance of that contract in ours.

```
Contract(Contract Address);
```

Since you need to access this instance more than once in your contract, you can define a variable of the contract type and declare it during compile time. So, the contract will not have to create a new instance of the contract every time you need to access its values.

```
Contract variable = Contract(Contract Address)
```

Here, this variable will help as mentioned.

Comment: im a little confused here. the line in question was ERC721 asset = ERC721(_assetAddress);  but your example is using brackets

Comment: My mistake. I updated the brackets.